# Angular2: Why isn't subscribe allowed on Subscriber object?

Tags: angular

If I have an observable object o :

```
let o: Observable<Object> = ...
```

I can to subscribe to do this object but why isn't that allowed to subscribe to the Subscriber object. To give a real world example :

```
  myServiceCall() {
    let o: Observable<Object> = ...
    return o.subscribe(...)
   }

   ngOnInit() {
     this.myServiceCall().subscribe(...) // Not allowed on a Subscriber object
   }
```

With promises, that would be like using several then in a row. I don't see why it is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `myServiceCall` method returns a subcription and not an observable. And you can't subscribe on a subscription. This object provides a `unsubscribe` method to cancel the subscription against the observable.

An option could be to use the `do` operator:

```
myServiceCall() {
  let o: Observable<Object> = ...
  return o.do((data) => { // <----
    // do something with the received data without subscribing
  });
 }

 ngOnInit() {
   this.myServiceCall().subscribe(...) // Not allowed on a Subscriber object
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`subscribe()` returns a `Subscription` not an `Observable`. You can't subscribe to an `Subscription`.

Use instead

```
  myServiceCall() {
    let o: Observable<Object> = ...
    return o.map(...)
   }

   ngOnInit() {
     this.myServiceCall().subscribe(...) // Not allowed on a Subscriber object
   }
```